# Indentation of bullet points in R pagedown resume

Tags: css, r, indentation, pagedown

I want to create a resume using the {pagedown} `resume` template. Overall, it's a great fit, but when I use bullet points, I would like to align the second line of text to the first one.

Here is the current state:

[image]

I would like to align the `w` in the second line to the `E` in the first one.

I guess, this needs to be set somewhere in the `resume.css`, but I have not found anything related (but I don't really know CSS, so that means nothing).

Any ideas how to accomplish that?